# Google Pubsub Push Subscription Response Body

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a pubsub push subscription pointed at a 3rd party endpoint. Sometimes the endpoint rejects the push. I can detect errors by either (1) looking at HTTP response codes on Stackdriver or (2) creating a dead letter topic. However, to help debug the rejection, we need information that is contained in the body of the response from the 3rd party endpoint. Is there any way to access this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access this directly via Pub/Sub, no. If you need access to it, you may consider proxying requests to the 3rd party endpoint via a Cloud Function tied to your subscription. Your function could forward the request to the 3rd party endpoint and if it gets back an error, it could manually write the response to a dead-letter topic at which point you would ack the message received from Pub/Sub.